# What's an example of an unsolvable finite group without an alternating group in its composition series?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

The only examples I have seen have had an alternating group in the composition series.

Comment: The smallest if the group $L_3(2) \cong L_2(7)$ of order 168. It is isomorphic to the multiplicative group of $3 \times 3$ non-singular matrices with entries in the finite field of order 2.

Answer (score 7):

Any nonabelian finite simple group that is not isomorphic to an alternating group.

For example, any of the [simple sporadic groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_sporadic_group) such as the Mathieu groups, the Monster, of the Baby Monster. Or almost all finite simple groups of Lie type (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_finite_simple_groups)), as there are only a couple of exceptions where they correspond to alternating groups (just like $A_3$ is alternating and simple, but not unsolvable).